# Management Studio won't recognize other file extensions

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am using SSMS 2012. I am working with .PRC, .TAB, and .UDF files. I added these file extensions to SSMS so that it would treat them like .SQL files already via Tools > Options > Text Editor > File Extension, but recently SSMS has stopped recognizing these files (e.g. won't show them with color coding or allow me to run them against a database). Funnily enough when I remove a file extension from a file it then recognizes them because it has "Map extensionless files to SQL Query Editor" checked.

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: Try adding it without the leading period (.): http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175896.aspx

Comment: None of them have been added with the leading period (SSMS doesn't let you add one with e leading period).

Comment: So it worked for some time, then it stopped working? Anything happen at that time (e.g. did you install a new version of Management Studio, or uninstall anything, or install Visual Studio or SQL Server Data Tools, etc.)? What is your version of Management Studio (Help > About) and are you saying it's broken in both 2012 and 2008, or only one?

Comment: I didn't install or uninstall anything in that time. Also I was slightly mistaken - I only have the 2008 engine installed, not the 2008 SSMS. So I'm only using SSMS 2012.

Comment: Help >  About:

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      11.0.3128.0

Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools      11.0.3128.0

Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      6.1.7601.17514

Microsoft MSXML      3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 

Microsoft Internet Explorer      9.11.9600.16518

Microsoft .NET Framework      4.0.30319.18444

Operating System      6.1.7601

Comment: @tuseau So, again, it was working and stopped working? Or it never worked at all?

Comment: It was working and then stopped working. Basically it was working on day (yesterday), then stopped working today. The only significant thing that happened was a restart.

Comment: This should have been fixed with SP1 (which you have applied to your client tools). See if [the manual steps described here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1307439-2799-1.aspx) work... also see [this Connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/712599/cannot-map-file-extensions-to-sql-query-editor-in-ssms-2012).

Comment: Thanks, the registry keys seemed to work for me today. I'm sure I had tried them already. Seems to be some temperamental behavior with SSMS.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with SSMS 2014. It was working at some point but no longer.

Comment: Is working now for me in SSMS 2014 (12.0.5203.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this Connect item](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/712599/cannot-map-file-extensions-to-sql-query-editor-in-ssms-2012), this bug was fixed in Service Pack 1.

However, if the issue persists, you can try [this convoluted workaround posted over at SQLServerCentral by Marios Philippopoulos](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1307439-2799-1.aspx):

> OK, got it to work with help from http://www.progtown.com/topic374931-sql-server-2012-rtm.html.
>   
>   
>   Opened regedit.exe as Administrator.
>   
>   
>   Then:
>   
>   
>   On [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\11.0\FileExtensionMapping\PRC] I changed the Default key value to {B5A506EB-11BE-4782-9A18-21265C2CA0B4}.
>   
>   
>   On [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\11.0\Default Editors\PRC] I changed the Custom key value to {B5A506EB-11BE-4782-9A18-21265C2CA0B4}.

Answer (score 0):

For me who had just the same problem, the easiest solution was to add the extensions I wanted (PRC,TAB,TRG,UDF) and mark them against `SQL Query Editor` as you can see on the picture below.

With that done I have the `.tab` files having the same treatment as the `.sql` ones.

There was no need to fiddle with the [regedit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/189063/22336).
[image]

I am on SSMS v18.12.1

[image]